# Jquery : append li to ul, ul.length always equals 1

Tags: jquery, list, append

I'm building a  list dynamically using:

```
$("#Selected ul").append($liObject);
```

Adding works, the issue is when I call:

```
alert($("#Selected ul").length)
```

It always returns 1 even if I added more items.
Thanks

Comment: That's right; no matter how many li's you add to the ul, you still have only one ul. You're counting the wrong thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting the list, not the children of it. What you should do is this:

```
$("#Selected ul").children().length
```

or

```
$("#Selected ul li").length
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("#Selected ul").children().length
```

Answer (score 1):

You're appending your `<li>` *to* that `<ul>`, not creating *more* `<ul>` elements (well maybe, if they're children of `$liObject`, but your results don't point to that being the case).

To get the number of [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) you'll need the [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) of that collection, like this:

```
alert($("#Selected ul").children().length)
```

Or a bit cleaner:

```
alert($("#Selected ul li").length)
```